# XmlTextReader node value not the same as value set

Tags: c#, xml

I've a XmlTextReader initialized by a memorystream, and the value in MemoryStream is :

```
<val><![CDATA[value]]></val>
```

In MemoryStream I've the good byte array corresponding to this value, but when I do :

```
XmlTextReader reader = new XmlTextReader(myMemoryStream);
reader.ReadToFollowing("val");
string result = reader.ReadElementContentAsString();
```

I get the following `result` value  :

> "\r\n\t\t\t\tvalue\r\n\t\t\t"

Why carriage returns and tabulations are appened to the value? I don't add it when I create the reader...

Hope I'm clear enough.

Thanks for help.

[EDIT]

```
    byte[] DEBUGvalue = myMemoryStream.GetBuffer()
                                      .SkipWhile((b) => b != (byte)'[')
                                      .TakeWhile((b) => b != (byte)']')
                                      .Select((b) => b).ToArray();
```

And DEBUGvalue contains :

```
    [0] 91  byte ([)
    [1] 67  byte (C)
    [2] 68  byte (D)
    [3] 65  byte (A)
    [4] 84  byte (T)
    [5] 65  byte (A)
    [6] 91  byte ([)
    [7] 118 byte (v)
    [8] 97  byte (a)
    [9] 108 byte (l)
    [10]    117 byte (u)
    [11]    101 byte (e)
    [12]    32  byte ( )
    [13]    32  byte ( )
    [14]    32  byte ( )
    [15]    32  byte ( )
    [16]    32  byte ( )
```

Comment: You should never use `new XmlTextReader()`. It's been deprecated since .NET 2.0. Use `XmlReader.Create()` instead.

Comment: I've seen nothing about this deprecation. You know why it's deprecated? Thanks

Comment: you need to spend more time on Planet Earth: .NET 2.0 was a long time ago, and you mananaged to miss this. From [XmlTextReader Class](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/system.xml.xmltextreader.aspx): "In the .NET Framework version 2.0 release, the recommended practice is to create XmlReader instances using the XmlReader.Create method. This allows you to take full advantage of the new features introduced in this release."

Comment: I'm just "new" to C# ;-), we migrate from C / PowerBuilder programming  languages to C#, so I'm not up to date with all new things of 4.0 but working on it :)

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Are you sure this is the literal input for this result?
Have you tried dumping the memStream to a (debug) file and examen the contents?

`ReadElementContentAsString()` will concatenate CDATA and whitespace. It looks like your input is more like

```
<val>
    <![CDATA[value]]>
    </val>
```

Comment: Yes, it's that, CDATA is on a new line, that's why ! Thanks a lot :)

Comment: You can always apply a `.Trim()` to the result (treats all whitespace the same).

Comment: Or just read the CDATA content? Trim is too much in my case :/

Comment: Trim should only be a problem if "value" contains significant whitespace at the front or back.

Comment: Yes it the case, I've significant whitespace at front or back ;), so I read until encounter the first CDATA tag and now is ok.

Answer (score -1):

You could create your XmlReader like this.

```
 var settings = new XmlReaderSettings { IgnoreWhitespace = true };
 var reader = XmlReader.Create(new StringReader(@"<val>       <![CDATA[value]]>       </val>"), settings);
```

That would make things a bit easier.

Comment: Nope, Whitespace are significant for me ;), problem is already solved (see previous post and comments).

Comment: yep, i've read the post. Just thought it might be of value for someone else reading this post.

Comment: -1 please answer _this_ question, not the question of "someone else"

Comment: I've answered 'This' question! It's not clear from the original question that whitespace is significant, only from the comments.